# Multi-threaded MemoryStream

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application where I would like to keep a ZipArchiveEntry in resident memory but have it simultaneously accessible by multiple threads so they can all read from it.  However, I also want to be cognizant of my application's memory footprint and keeping the same data in multiple memory streams isn't very efficient.  Is there anything I can use that would allow multiple threads to read from the same MemoryStream concurrently?

Comment: Probably unwise, as the memory stream has a `Position` that would change as it is read.  You could share the backing array buffer, and have each thread wrap it in a `MemoryStream` as needed.

Comment: @Amy I understand that the I can't use the exact same `MemoryStream` for each thread because of the Position.  However, I don't want to store use x10 the memory for the same data.  If I create x10 MemoryStreams using the same byte array the CLR smart enough not to duplicate the memory usage?

Comment: The memory streams don't duplicate the array buffer.  You could have 100 memory streams wrapping the same buffer without killing yourself memory-wise.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this solves my issue.  I was just thinking about the wrong way.

Comment: I don't really feel like writing up a nice answer, so feel free to do so.  You can accept your own answer after a time-limit has elapsed.

Comment: Btw you can see for yourself that it does not duplicate the buffer:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,92