# How to copy a large video file into memory so I can write it later from memory

Tags: powershell

I am having to transfer a large video file to multiple USBs and I am trying to find a faster way to acheive this.

What I am after is a way to store the entire 26Gb video into memory and then do something like stream-write to copy the file off memory on the USBs. That way the storage isnt constantly benig used for multiple reads of the same file causing system slowdows. This is on a spinning platter raid storage.

I was thinking ether Get-Content -Raw or Set-Content -Stream but I am not sure about the file size? The server has 128Gb of Ram so loading into memory wont be an issue. I need to copy to 16 USBs at a time

Comment: It is probably possible to use a `MemoryStream` to store the video file content. And then create 16 new `MemoryStream` to read from the underlying `MemoryStream`. There is some information on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304764/multi-threaded-memorystream). Or this one about a [Multiplexer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345105/Memory-Stream-Multiplexer-write-and-read-from-many).

Comment: That is exactly what I was after thank you. Had never heard of it before